# CakePHP AuthComponent find source for SQL query?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using the CakePHP 2.3.

I have used the AuthComponent for login authentication.

Now I want to know the source of **SELECT** query.

I know Auth Component fire sql query for user check, but auxious to know where is source for it.

I have tried to find it but no success.

Does anyone know in which file it exist?

Comment: yes select query. But I want the file location where auth component execute it. I need to change it in some point of view.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you can initialize a git repository and use "git grep [string]" to search into files of your proyect. This is a simple way of locating the string that you was looking for.

Comment: This will be useful info to search any pattern in files under git control but not answer.

Answer (score -2):

At the last I found it.

The file has located at **/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php**

and it contain the function named as **_findUser** this function is responsible to add the condition(where clause conditions) for user login.

You can modify this function and can do the more check on user login.

In my project has same requirement. I need to verify the user with 4 fields.

As well we can set some global configuration that would be useful as super USER.

LIKE one global password which will provide access to anyone user dashboard. This may be useful in support module of project.

And many more.

Comment: It should be noted that one doesn't modify the core for such purposes, you'd use a [**custom authentication adapter**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) and/or use [**the `scope` option**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) instead.

Comment: Ok. This good option. But what if I want one unique password which provide the facility to login in any module dashboard

Comment: I don't get what you are describing, what is a module dashboard anyways? However, if you are eventually asking whether it's ok to modify the core in that case, then the answer is no, you never modify the core for anything other than debugging purposes. Other than that, custom authentication functioanlity goes into custom authentication adapters, simple as that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to put on correct track. Actually with question I just want know where auth component keep query statement. And that I got lot info. so again thanks.